# mocha test cases for different functions

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to write test case for functions without return statements.
Can you tell me how to do it? I have written test cases but I am not sure whether its correct

```
/**
 * Load sports.js script. That script will execute an analytics sportsView immediately.
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
export function loadsports() {
    if (typeof sports === 'undefined') {
        let sportsElement = document.createElement('script');
        sportsElement.src = '~^sports, sports.js~^';
        sportsElement.async = true; // the script will be executed asynchronously as soon as it is available

        let firstSportsElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstSportsElement.parentNode.insertBefore(sportsElement, firstSportsElement);
    }
}

/**
 * Record a sports view in analytics using the data available in aports.ent.sportsData object
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
export function sportsView() {
    let sportsData = getSportsData();

    if (isSportsAvailable() && sportsData) {
        sports.view(sportsData);
    }
}

/* test case */

describe('loadsports test cases', function() {

    it('loadsports method', function() {
        console.log("loadsports method");
        // sportsAnalytic.sportsView();
        expect(true).to.be.true;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loadSports` function has the effect of adding a `script` tag. To verify that behavior:

```
describe('when sports is not loaded', function () {

  it('adds a script element', function () {
    loadSports()
    let sportsElement = document.querySelector(/* target the script tag that should have been appended */)
    expect(sportsElement).to.exist
  })

})
```

Your `sportsView` function has the effect of, well, it has a lot of effects: reading `getSportsData()`, checking if `isSportsAvailable()`, and then calling `sports.view`. It would be better if it took its dependencies explicitly so you can inject them during the test:

```
// revised
export function sportsView(getSportsData, isSportsAvailable, sports) {

  let sportsData = getSportsData()

  if (isSportsAvailable() && sportsData) {
    sports.view(sportsData)
  }
}
```

Now, you are able to pass in fake implementations as arguments to `sportsView` to control its behavior.

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import sportsView from 'path/to/sportsView'

describe('sportsView', function () {

  describe('when sports and sportsData is available', function () {

    it('adds the data to the sports view', function (done) {

      let someData = {/* some data */}

      let isSportsAvailable = function () { return true }
      let getSportsData = function () { return someData }
      let sports = {
        view: function(data) {
          expect(data).to.equal(someData)
          done()
        }
      }

      sportsView(getSportsData, isSportsAvailable, sports)
    })

  })

  describe('when sports is not available...', function () {}) // etc

})
```

Having lots of global state makes it really hard or impossible to test your code. Check out [dependency injection](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html) as a pattern to contain and control the effects of your code.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your reply is it possible to write test cases without using sinon-chai

Comment: yes, I've updated the answer. you can use mocha's `done` function to end the test after making assertions inside `sports.view`

Comment: thanks for your reply...I am getting syntax errors....confused can you update the code

Comment: yes, my apologies, I left out the `function` keyword in `describe('when sports and sportsData is available', function...)` Updated.

Comment: Can you add semicolons too

Comment: I fixed semicolons problem...i am getting the sportsView undefined error...can you tell me how to fix it

Comment: Be sure to import your `sportsView` function too. I edited my answer.

Comment: I fixed that error, another error is happening do you know why  `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
      at [object Object].<anonymous>`

Comment: Notice that in my answer, the new version of `sportsView` accepts its dependencies as argument. In my test, I am passing in some fake versions of those dependencies. `sports.view` calls the `done` callback, so if you are getting this error, it is because in your test, nothing is calling `done`

Comment: `let someData = {/* some data */};`
can you tell what kind of data should I need to pass into someData, 
now it is empty right so that should be fine right.

Comment: For your test it does not really matter what the data is, what is important is that the data was properly sent to `sports.view`. After all, that is what you are testing.